# Python create a new column and populates it based on two other columns values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this df:

| ID | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 60 |
| 2 | 60 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 30 |

I need to add a new column to indicate whether each id has two values in a new column like the below:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 60 | 2 |
| 2 | 60 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 30 | 1 |

I tried this but it is not returning the right values

```
df= pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby('ID') if len(g) > 1)
df= df[df['A'] != 0]
df= pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby('A') if len(g) > 1)
df['B'] = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using groupby to take a count of values greater than 0 for each ID, and then merging back with the original df

```
df.merge(df[df['A'] > 0].groupby('ID').size().reset_index(name='count'), on='ID')
```

```
    ID  A   count
0   1   40  1
1   1   0   1
2   2   60  2
3   2   60  2
4   3   0   1
5   3   30  1
```

Comment: thank you very much! that is exactly what I was trying to do. Much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Another option, no need to merge, let pandas handle alignment using groupby and transform.

```
df['count'] = df.assign(count=df['A'] != 0).groupby('ID')['count'].transform('sum')
df
```

Output:

```
   ID   A  count
0   1  40      1
1   1   0      1
2   2  60      2
3   2  60      2
4   3   0      1
5   3  30      1
```